# MDX Count of LastNonEmpty Within Another Dimension

Tags: sql-server, ssas, mdx

I am just a beginner in MDX. The problem I have on hand is the following:

I have a Fact table which has the roughly the format below:

[image]

I have to create a report that, based on any selection of date on the report, we want to see the total number of tasks whose last TaskStatusID was a particular value.

For example, based on the data above, if the user selects 11 November 2017 and TaskStatus as CLOSED on the report, there should be one task returned (100) because the last member before 11 November for TaskID 100 was Closed(4th row) and for TaskID 101 was Completed(last row), hence rejected.

Similary, if the user selects 13 November 2017 and OPEN, then nothing should be returned, as TaskID 100 has 3 three rows for the date, but we only take the latest which is CLOSED and hence not considered, similary TaskID 101's latest row(last row in the data above) is COMPLETED hence not considered.

I have tried solving this using a custom last non empty MDX query for Total Open Tasks (TaskStatusID = 2) on 11 November 2017:

```
WITH MEMBER Measures.LatestMember AS
TAIL(NONEMPTY({NULL:[Date].[Date].CURRENTMEMBER} * [IsLastInADay].&[1], Measures.CountOfRows))
MEMBER Measures.Count AS
COUNT(NONEMPTY([DimTask].[TaskID].MEMBERS * [DimTaskStatus].[TaskStatusID].&2], Measures.LatestMember))
SELECT 
Measures.Count ON 0,
[Date].[Date].&[20171111] ON 1
FROM [Cube Name]
```

But this is taking forever to execute. My Fact Table consists of around 40 million rows, and has about 8 million distinct tasks, and the data is scattered over 10 years.

Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated, including changes in the Fact Table design or moving some of the complexity to ETL process.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this sort of approach is quicker?

```
WITH 
MEMBER Measures.LatestMember AS
TAIL(
  NONEMPTY(
    {NULL:[Date].[Date].CURRENTMEMBER} * [IsLastInADay].&[1]
   , Measures.CountOfRows
  )
)
MEMBER Measures.Count AS
SUM(
  [DimTask].[TaskID].MEMBERS * [DimTaskStatus].[TaskStatusID].&2]
  IIF(
    Not(IsEmpty(Measures.LatestMember))
   ,1
   ,NULL
  )
)
SELECT 
Measures.Count ON 0,
[Date].[Date].&[20171111] ON 1
FROM [Cube Name];
```